# Non-exhaustive patterns in function(lists)

Tags: haskell

i've write this code, that allows me to find a maximum on a list and return this maximum and the rest of the list. For example:
maximoYresto [1,2,3,4,2] = (4,[1,2,3,2]).

The code is this:

```
maximoYresto :: Ord a => [a] -> (a,[a])
maximoYresto [] = error "error"
maximoYresto [x] = (maximum [x], filter (\x -> x < maximum [x]) [x])
```

but i get this error:

Exception: relacion2.hs:(31,1)-(32,68): Non-exhaustive patterns in function maximoYresto.

Thanks.

Comment: The `maximoYresto` function handles the cases `[]` and `[x]`. Can you think of any other cases of input that doesn't fall into one of these cases?

Comment: @MarkSeemann i think has to be the case of a non existing maximum, for example [2,2]. Can u help with that?

Comment: What does `[]` mean? What does `[x]` mean? Can you think of other list values that don't fall into one of these patterns?

Comment: @MarkSeemann i dont know another case...

Comment: `[x]` matches with a list having exactly one element. If you want to match with any list just use a variable name without brackets, e.g. `x` or `list`.

Comment: @chi so much thanks dude, im newbie in functional programming. Thanks a lot!